# jComboBox giving org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException error

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

There is 2 `jComboBox` .. and 2 Class . When form load event it will fill `jComboBox1`,when `ActionEvent` fired it will load another class with selection of the jComboBox1.

I wanna get PersonelID from `jComboBox.GetSelectItem` method than call another class with this id. But gettin this error ;

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" 
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: 
could not get a field value by reflection getter of DBClasses.Unvan.unvanID
```

And Here is my Codes.;

```
 private void UnvanAl()
{
if (jComboBox1.getSelectedItem() != null) {
         EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("SwingDenemePU");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    Query sorgu = em.createQuery("select p from Personel p where p.unvanID = :id");
    int id = ((Unvan)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()).getUnvanID();

    sorgu.setParameter("id", id);
    personelList = sorgu.getResultList();
    Object[] items = new Object[personelList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < personelList.size(); i++) {
        Personel personel = personelList.get(i);
        items[i]=personel.getPersonelAdSoyad();

    }

    DefaultComboBoxModel def = new DefaultComboBoxModel(items);
    jComboBox2.setModel(def);
    }

}


private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   UnvanAl();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have getters/setters for the property "unvanID"?

Comment: post as comment and not as answer